# Laravel Eloquent - One to Many - Can't join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.4, have two models ParentAccount and ChildAccount,
A parent has many childs

Parent

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ParentAccount extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'parent_accounts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'account_id'
    ];
    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ChildAccount','account_id', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

child

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ChildAccount extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'child_accounts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'account_id','parent_id'
    ];
}
```

When i use echo ParentAccount::find(1)->childs();
i get an error Call to a member function childs() on null although all parents have children

Note: child has parent_id where it's the account_id in the parent

Comment: Change the primary key in the parent model and the child model to be `account_id` not `id`!!

Comment: @Maraboc but i have defined it in the hasmany function, so i don't need that, right ?

Comment: No it's not the case because in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models) you have `Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention.`

Comment: @Maraboc yes that would be required if using find(1), but if using all(), it won't work too!

Comment: If you did all you must loop over the elements then you can do `$parent->childs` !

Comment: ```$result = ParentAccount::whereAccountId(1)->with('childs')->get();```

Answer (score 6):

in parent model

```
public function childs(){
 return $this->hasMany(ChildAccount::class, 'parent_id' , 'account_id');
}
```

in child model

```
public function parent(){
 return $this->belongsTo(ParentAccount::class, 'parent_id' , 'account_id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Edited Code

```
public function childs()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\ChildAccount', 'parent_id','account_id');
  }
```

The relation function must be in the format

```
public function post()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}
```

Comment: when i use         $parents= ParentAccount::with('childs')->get();
to get each parent with it's children, childs object is empty

Comment: nvm got it, was declaring account_id as primarykey so it's length was limited

Answer (score 3):

First you have to add the `primaryKey` property then change the relation parameters and add the revers relation to the `ChildAccount` :

- **ParentAccount :**

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class ParentAccount extends Model
  {

      protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $table = 'parent_accounts';
      protected $fillable = [
          'name', 'account_id'
      ];
      public function childs()
      { 
         //                                        'foreign_key', 'local_key'
          return $this->hasMany('App\ChildAccount', 'parent_id', 'account_id');
      }
  }
  ```
- **ChildAccount :**

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class ChildAccount extends Model
  {
      protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $table = 'child_accounts';
      protected $fillable = [
          'name', 'account_id','parent_id'
      ];

      public function parent() {
          //                                           foreign_key, 'other_key'
          return $this->belongsTo('App\ParentAccount', 'parent_id', 'account_id');
      }

  }
  ```

With doing that you can get the childs :

```
ParentAccount::find(1)->childs;
```

Comment: @JenuRudan this will give you the wanted result i hope ;)

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka i missed it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. You got `Call to a member function childs() on null` because `ParentAccount::find(1)` return `null`. Make sure you have ParentAccount with id=1 in your DB.
2. You need to change keys order like this:

   ```
   public function childs()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\ChildAccount', 'parent_id', 'account_id');
   }
   ```